# determinant of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we consider a complex $n\times n$ matrix $A$. It can be writen generally as $A=U+iV$, where $U$, $V$ are $n\times n$ real matrices.

Now I hope to study the determinant of the following matrix
$$B\equiv\pmatrix{0 & U-iV\\
U+iV & 0}.$$

We shall have $\det(B)=\det[-(U-iV)(U+iV)]=\det(-U^2-V^2-i[U,V])$.

On the other hand, matrix $B$ is similar to $C$: $B=T^{-1}CT$ where
$$C=\pmatrix{U & -V\\
-V & -U}$$ and
$$T=\pmatrix{\mathbf{1} & i\mathbf{1}\\
\mathbf{1} & -i\mathbf{1}}$$
with $\mathbf{1}$ being the $n\times n$ unit matrix.

Then we have $\det(B)=\det(C)$ but $\det(C)=(-U^2-V^2)$ (Is this right for this kind of block matrix? If not, then my question is the in the comment.). Then how to show that 
$$\det(-U^2-V^2-i[U,V])=\det (-U^2-V^2)?$$

Comment: You can't in general say that $\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} A & B\\C& D\end{bmatrix}\right) = \det (AD-CB)$ unless $A$ and $C$ (or $B$ and $D$) commute.

Comment: Even though, I never have imaginary $i$ from the determinant of C, right? But in the expression of the determinant B, there is $-i[U,V]$. How can I see then $\det B=\det C$?

Comment: I don't think your formula for your matrix $C$ is correct unless you know $U$ and $V$ commute. That is the point of my original comment.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment. Yes, I agree the expression for $\det C$ could be incorrect. But maybe my question is, how to understand the imaginary part $-i[U,V]$ in the expression of $\det B$ since in $\det C$ there is no any imaginary part anyway. I know the imaginary part in $\det B$ could be vanishing at the end but just have no insight on how it can be that case.

Comment: I agree that the answer should be real. A simple $4\times 4$ example I've tried shows that neither formula is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you very much for your comment. Could you please post as an answer your calculation showing that the formula for $\det B$ is incorrect? This could be already the answer that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take $U=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $V=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Then $UV\ne VU$, as is easy to check.
Now,
$$\det\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & -i & 1-i \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & -i \\ i & 1+i & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & i & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 5,$$
whereas $\det(U^2+V^2)=4$.

Now, we should have (with $n\times n$ blocks) $\det\left[\begin{array}{c|c} 0 & X \\\hline Y & 0 \end{array}\right] = (-1)^n\det\left[\begin{array}{c|c} X& 0 \\\hline 0 & Y \end{array}\right] = (-1)^n\det X\det Y$. In our case, with $X=U-iV$ and $Y=U+iV = \bar X$, we get $|\det(U+iV)|^2 = |2+i|^2 = 5$, which checks. It also checks with your original formula, because the commutator gives complex conjugate entries on the diagonal.